# GetOverriddenBrowser() for ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, 51degrees

ASP.NET MVC 4 has some nice mobile features which are replacing my mutant mobile view engines, but until it's production ready, I'd like to implement the browser override feature for ASP.NET MVC 3.

`SetOverriddenBrowser()` seems to set a `.ASPXBrowserOverride` cookie with an overriding User Agent that returns an `HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase` object via `HttpContext.GetOverriddenBRowser()`.

What would be the simplest way of implementing this feature for MVC 3 to make use of the mobile detection library, including 51Degrees.mobi?

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post on the 51Degrees.mobi site that you might find useful. Check it out [here](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/26/51Degrees-mobi-and-MVC4.aspx?CATReferrer=1765). It covers the implementation of 51Degrees with MVC 4.